# Multicloud load balancer (Firebase and Digital Ocean)

Tags: firebase, digital-ocean, firebase-hosting

I'm currently running my webapp on **Firebase Hosting** under the free tier, but I am about to start advertising a little bit, meaning I will drive consistently traffic to the website with clear in mind that the conversion rate, aka purchases, will be really low (I'd be happy if 0.1% converts xD).

To avoid incurring in huge cost from Firebase, without a relative return, would it be possible to turn on

```
1 Load Balancer
1 Instance (small, 5 eur/month)
```

on **Digital Ocean** with a replica of the website and drive traffic also there with 1 of the following possible patterns?

1. **50-50**, halving the load on Firebase at the very least
2. (best, but not sure if possible) hit Firebase Hosting **only** when Digital Ocean is **reaching saturation**

Is it feasible in any way? Do you have previous experience on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to implement a load balancer like that. But that's a quite involved and advanced project, and I'd seriously consider whether it's worth it for this type of optimization.

From the [Digital Ocean docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/accounts/billing/bandwidth/):

> Droplets include free outbound data transfer, starting at 1000 GB/month for the smallest plan. Excess data transfer is billed at $.01/GB.

And for Firebase Hosting:

> Free/Spark plan: GB transferred: 10 GB/month
>
> Metered/Blaze plan: GB transferred: $0.15/GB (with the first 10GB/month being non-charged)

If you're going for pure bandwidth cost, it seems that your Digital Ocean droplet is always going to be cheaper. Also: the free quota on Firebase is 100x smaller than the included bandwidth in your Digital Ocean plan. Are you really looking to shed load from Digital Ocean to Firebase for a 1% increase in the quota?

For hosting of static content, I'd recommend finding a single host that has a pricing plan that fits with what you're willing to pay. It's just not worth the overhead of coming up with your own load balancer.

If instead you are looking for a load balancer that somebody else already built (or a tutorial on how to build one), those questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow and are a better fit for your favorite search engine. If you get stuck while implementing the load balancer, post back with the concrete question about where you got stuck.